# TYPO3: Make a new register type with Kickstarter and use it with tt_news

Tags: typo3, tt-news

So I have this challenge on TYPO3. Every entry in tt_news has to have a slideshow with images and videos. There is also a navigation next to it for all images. Videos of course must have a small "poster" image.

I couldnt think of any way to natively do this with tt_news so I thought the best way was to make a new record type, like "slideshow item", where you can upload either images or videos with a poster images, and then later extend tt_news with a combobox where you can add the items you want to add to the slider on that tt_news entry.

My problem is: How do I create a new record type? Ive looked up and down on Kickstarter and I havent found a way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new record Type in the backend, you just have to create a new table using Kickstarter. This will automatically add a new record Type with the name of the table you've created, which you might be able to create under SysFolder (or other pages if configured so)